# Any documented REST/Golang API for the 'new' Firebase?

Tags: rest, go, firebase

Has anyone seen note of if the **REST** API's are being continued for the new Firebase (I don't know what to call it other than 'new' - the current updates that were announced at Google I/O).  I asked support - but I'm a few days in without a response.  Just trying REST with random parameters on a new format index didn't do anything useful.

The updates look really good - but I have a lot of already existing REST code (mostly from Go) and I don't know what to do other than dig through the JavaScript and start hacking the Go libraries.  If I'm going to get cut off there's not point even starting, and if there's an official interface on the way it's definitely not worth messing with.

Any help appreciated.  :)

Comment: This might be better asked on the Go mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/golang-nuts

Comment: The question makes sense to me. Stack overflow is now just filled with dead end queries closed by zealots :(

Comment: This is a good question and I don't know why it's closed.